# WP8.1 (UWP) Bing Map Route Multiple Points

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

Here's an interesting one. I want to do [this](https://www.bing.com/mapspreview?v=2&cp=53.239819~-1.744080&lvl=7&sty=r&rtp=pos.52.292375_-2.337527_near%20Structon%27s%20Heath,%20Great%20Witley,%20WR6%206___a_~pos.52.728662_-1.768984_near%20Daisy%20Lane,%20Alrewas,%20DE13%207___a_~pos.53.222777_-1.325843_near%20North%20East%20Derbyshire___a_~pos.54.175975_-1.465155_near%20Harrogate,%20North%20Yorkshire___a_&mode=D&rtop=0~0~0~&form=LMLTCC) but in my WP8.1 app using the map control. I am using VS2013/C#. I need to be able to get the route data and save/send it somewhere else.

I can already do a route between two points easily enough using the Bing Maps API. Now I want to go further and create a route from multiple points and show push pins, like in the example link.

Answer (score 0):

Well Surprisingly easy after some digging. Just reading through the articles in the link below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx

I can get a route and plot the poly line althoug it doesn't exactly follow the line of the road.

Switching from VS2012 fully to VS2012 (took a while to get my projects into a state I could migrate them.) I did discover that you can't add a service reference yo a WP8.1 project. Wasn't a big deal as I've been messing with Json for a while now so it didn't slow me down.